# REST API object conversion in java

Tags: web-services, java-8, spring-rest, spring-webclient

I have request body of supplier in below format :

```
{
  "supplier": {
    "supplierData": {
      "supplierAddress": {
        "street": "abc",
        "postCode": "1234",
        "city1": "abcd",
        "country": "DE",
        "region": "BW"
      },
      "location": {
        "locationID": "1234",
        "locationName": "South Africa "
      },
      "lastUpdatedDateTime": "2022-06-28T10:07:37.000Z"
    }    
  }
}
```

able to consume it and need to know how to consume the below body request for Location object as null instead of string :

```
{
  "supplier": {
    "supplierData": {
      "supplierAddress": {
        "street": "abc",
        "postCode": "1234",
        "city1": "abcd",
        "country": "DE",
        "region": "BW"
      },
      "location": "null",
      "lastUpdatedDateTime": "2022-06-28T10:07:37.000Z"
    }    
  }
}
```

Any idea how we would do it.

Comment: Please share some code and create minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to parse this into a defined POJO. And also assuming that `Location` must be an `Object`, otherwise (a `string`), it is `null`, then you can try parse it:

```
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(jsonString); //use your parser library method

Location location = null;

try{
     JSONObject jo2 = jo.getJsonObject(location);
     //parse jo2 into location
}
catch(JSONException e){
     //if exception is throw, it would mean the location data is a string, which can only be "null"
}
```